# How to correctly pass props in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using this react component as part of my react app. However, when I pass in a number via a prop (as shown below), it doesn't work. It works perfectly if I write a number though.

The code is from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-using-reactjs/

and I'd like to create many instances of the timer for different sections of my website, which is why I need to pass in props.

Does anyone know what the issue is?
Thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'


const Timer = ({time}) => {

    // We need ref in this, because we are dealing
    // with JS setInterval to keep track of it and
    // stop it when needed
    const Ref = useRef(null);

    // The state for our timer
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState('00:00:00');

    const getTimeRemaining = (e) => {
        const total = Date.parse(e) - Date.parse(new Date());
        const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
        const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        const hours = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24);
        return {
            total, hours, minutes, seconds
        };
    }


    const startTimer = (e) => {
        let { total, hours, minutes, seconds }
                    = getTimeRemaining(e);
        if (total >= 0) {

            // update the timer
            // check if less than 10 then we need to
            // add '0' at the beginning of the variable
            setTimer(
                (hours > 9 ? hours : '0' + hours) + ':' +
                (minutes > 9 ? minutes : '0' + minutes) + ':'
                + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : '0' + seconds)
            )
        }
    }


    const clearTimer = (e) => {

        // If you adjust it you should also need to
        // adjust the Endtime formula we are about
        // to code next 
        setTimer('00:00:10');

        // If you try to remove this line the
        // updating of timer Variable will be
        // after 1000ms or 1sec
        if (Ref.current) clearInterval(Ref.current);
        const id = setInterval(() => {
            startTimer(e);
        }, 1000)
        Ref.current = id;
    }

    const getDeadTime = () => {
        let deadline = new Date();

        // This is where you need to adjust if
        // you entend to add more time
        deadline.setSeconds(deadline.getSeconds() + {time});
        return deadline;
    }

    // We can use useEffect so that when the component
    // mount the timer will start as soon as possible

    // We put empty array to act as componentDid
    // mount only
    useEffect(() => {
        clearTimer(getDeadTime());
    }, []);

    // Another way to call the clearTimer() to start
    // the countdown is via action event from the
    // button first we create function to be called
    // by the button
    const onClickReset = () => {
        clearTimer(getDeadTime());
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2 className='text-3xl lg:text-4xl text-white'>{timer}</h2>
            <button onClick={onClickReset}>Reset</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Timer;
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct? `(deadline.getSeconds() + {time}` ? I don't think adding with `+` a number and an object works as you intend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need curly braces to add the time.

```
deadline.setSeconds(deadline.getSeconds() + time);
```

Comment: I knew it was something silly. Thanks!!!